# Autocomplete do Google Maps não mostra o endereço

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Estou tentando fazer com que meu autocomplete do Google Maps mostre o endereço no formado "Cidade - Estado, País" porém, está me retornando isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resumindo: só retorna com a cidade, mas não dá para saber de onde ela é.

Testei dessa forma:

```
var input = document.getElementById('address');

$(function () {
    var options = {
       types: ['(cities)']
    };
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
});
```

E no JS:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=****&libraries=places"></script>
```

Mesmo que eu retire o `types: ['(cities)']` continua sem mostrar o resto do endereço.

Deixei algo a fazer?

Comment: Acredito que uma forma possível seja usar o serviço e colocar vc mesmo em um select. Da uma olhada neste exemplo aqui https://jsfiddle.net/b1ws2h07/69/